# Django is not rendering second applications HTML

Tags: python, django

I've added a second application using:

```
python manage.py startapp about
```

in my project.  However now it is rendering my first applications only view, no matter what URL I put on.

Ex. http://127.0.0.1:8000/aldsjfal/asdfadsfa/adsfasdf/adfadsf/

Here is my settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/
"""

import os
################################################################################
#                                      Dependencies                            #
################################################################################
import os.path                                                                # 
#                                                                              #
# Note that we use os.path to construct the absolute path. This ensures Django#
# can locate the files unambiguously for STATICFILES_DIRS. - LT 16JAN2016      #                      
#                                                                              #
#                                                                              #
#                                                                              #
################################################################################

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '*ih=!lu+z1=5sk8&ool2hmryc07rbuhjwy*3745=i6@$w)joo7'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

Temp_Path = os.path.realpath('.')

PROJECT_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

MEDIA_ROOT = PROJECT_PATH + '/media/'


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [

    'about.apps.AboutConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'home.apps.HomeConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

----------------------------------EDIT 1----------------------------------

Here is my urls.py from the root project:

```
"""mysite URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Add an import:  from blog import urls as blog_urls
    2. Import the include() function: from django.conf.urls import url, include
    3. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^blog/', include(blog_urls))
"""
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^about/', include('about.urls'), name ='about'),
    url(r'^', include('home.urls'), name ='index'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Here is my first application urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

app_name = 'home'

from . import views
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^', views.index, name ='index'),


]
```

Here is my second applications urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

app_name = 'about'

from . import views
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^/about/$', views.about, name ='about'),


]
```

Comment: Show us `urls.py` for both apps.

Answer (score 1):

The order of url patterns matter. It will return any first matching pattern at the top of the list, even though there could be more specific pattern at the bottom of the list.

also a pattern like: `r’^‘` will match anything. including: http://127.0.0.1:8000/abc/def/ghi/. However, normally such pattern will include another nested urlpattern, where they usually will be closed with some kind of `r'^$'`, which match nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "about" app in your settings.py file under the INSTALLED_APPS. Like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [

'about.apps.AboutConfig',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'home.apps.HomeConfig',
'about',
]
```

Comment: By adding 'about', should I be removing 'about.apps.AboutConfig'? Why?

Comment: If you've added "about" app in this way 'about.apps.AboutConfig' then yes. You need to remove it.

Comment: No, nonsense. The settings file is fine.

Comment: @DanielRoseman but in INSTALLED_APPS, he didn't mention the new app "about".

Answer (score 0):

Go to `url.py` and **configure** the **URL** like:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(‘’,
    url(r’^$’, HomePageView.as_view(), name=‘home’),
    url(r’^about/‘, include(‘blog.urls’)),
    ...
)
```

Go to `settings.py` and add more eventual modules:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [

    'about.apps.AboutConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'home.apps.HomeConfig',
    'new_module',
]
```